# How to insert values into a nested dictionary from existing dictionary values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is like a json format. Like below:-

```
dito1 ={'result2':[{'math':20,'science':22,'english':31},{'math':26,'science':27,'english':33},
                                    {'math':15,'science':55,'english':44}],'pet2':0,
                                    'result':[{'rt':66,'io':49,'op':10},{'rt':24,'io':25,'op':5}],'pet':20}
```

Now I want to create a new dictionary using the above values, the new dictionary has to be seen like below:-

```
{'type': 'etc', 'scores': [{'math': 20, 'science': 22, 'english': 31}, {'math': 26, 'science': 27, 'english': 33}, {'math': 15, 'science': 55, 'english': 44}], 'math total': 61,'scores2':[{'math': 66, 'science': 49, 'english': 10}, {'math': 24, 'science': 25, 'english': 5}],'math total':90}
```

In the first dictionary there are two keys result2, result that have scores information that are lists. By using this information they must be converted as above and the math total in the second dictionary is total marks of the math's in each list. I have tried to get the desired output but I am not able to divide them into two based on the keys they belong to. The code I have tried is as follows:-

```
dito1 ={'result2':[{'math':20,'science':22,'english':31},{'math':26,'science':27,'english':33},
                                    {'math':15,'science':55,'english':44}],'pet2':0,
                                    'result':[{'rt':66,'io':49,'op':10},{'rt':24,'io':25,'op':5}],'pet':20}
reslt=[]
math_total=[]
for key,value in dito1.items():
    if key == 'result' or key == 'result2':
        for i in value:
            for k,v in i.items():
                if k == 'math':
                    t=v
                if k == 'rt':
                    t=v
                if k == 'science':
                    r=v
                if k == 'io':
                    r=v
                if k=='op':
                    e=v
                if k=='english':
                    e=v
            rest ={'math':t,'science':r,'english':e}
            math_total.append(t)
            reslt.append(rest)

final_dict={'type':'etc','math total':reslt,'scores':sum(math_total)}
    
print(final_dict)
```

The output I got is:-

```
{'type': 'etc', 'scores': [{'math': 20, 'science': 22, 'english': 31}, {'math': 26, 'science': 27, 'english': 33}, {'math': 15, 'science': 55, 'english': 44}, {'math': 66, 'science': 49, 'english': 10}, {'math': 24, 'science': 25, 'english': 5}], 'math total': 151}
```

Excepted output:-

```
{'type': 'etc', 'scores': [{'math': 20, 'science': 22, 'english': 31}, {'math': 26, 'science': 27, 'english': 33}, {'math': 15, 'science': 55, 'english': 44}], 'math total': 61,'scores2':[{'math': 66, 'science': 49, 'english': 10}, {'math': 24, 'science': 25, 'english': 5}],'math total2':90}
```

Comment: Could you check/confirm the keys in your expected output? It has the key `'math total'` twice.

Comment: I think that's by design. He wants to calculate the ```math_total``` for both dictionaries

Comment: @pyzer Yes. I want to calculate

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Sorry forgot to add new name for the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside, I'd suggest re-thinking the structure/naming scheme of this `final_dict`; using keys like `'scores'` and `'scores2'` indicates you may want a `list` structure instead of a `dict` structure.

```py
dito1 = {'result2': [{'math': 20, 'science': 22, 'english': 31}, {'math': 26, 'science': 27, 'english': 33}, {'math': 15, 'science': 55, 'english': 44}], 'pet2': 0, 'result': [{'rt': 66, 'io': 49, 'op': 10}, {'rt': 24, 'io': 25, 'op': 5}], 'pet': 20}

translate = {'rt':'math','io':'science','op':'english'}

final_dict = {'type':'etc'}
for key,list_of_dict in dito1.items():
    if key in ['result', 'result2']:
        score_key = key.replace('result','scores')
        final_dict[score_key] = []

        math_total_key = key.replace('result','math_total')
        final_dict[math_total_key] = 0
        for d in list_of_dict:
            # translate to the intended score names as needed
            for k in ['rt','io','op']:
                if k in d:
                    d[translate[k]] = d.pop(k)

            # append the scores to the appropriate nested dict
            final_dict[score_key].append(dict(d))
            # and increment the math_total for that set of scores
            final_dict[math_total_key] += d['math']
print(final_dict)
```

results in

```py
for key,value in final_dict.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')

# Output:
type: etc
scores2: [{'math': 20, 'science': 22, 'english': 31}, {'math': 26, 'science': 27, 'english': 33}, {'math': 15, 'science': 55, 'english': 44}]
math_total2: 61
scores: [{'math': 66, 'science': 49, 'english': 10}, {'math': 24, 'science': 25, 'english': 5}]
math_total: 90
```